# strange mysql select loop with ; but not \G

Tags: mysql

We have a server with old php (5.2.9) and mysql (5.0.67). It's a site that's been working for years. Now it stuck.

With strace I saw it gets stuck on a select query

running the command from mysql

```
select * from table \G
```

works fine

```
select * from table;
```

does not stop running and running and running until I Ctrl+C it.

I know it's an ancient server and config but that's still strange, no?

Comment: Are you needing to pass the \G command because like you found out, ; works the same and is the intended command.

Comment: Now .. if its running forever .. is that statement  being passed in php or are you doing it directly in the database (MySQL Workbench/phpadmin)?  If its the former the php logic is stuck in a loop and not the database.  If it were ASP Classic that happens because its in a Do/Loop usually and they forgot to add MoveNext to the recordset so it just loops the same row forever.

Comment: Sounds like you changed the `DELIMITER` to something other than `;` so as far as the MySQL client knows, you haven't finished the query. Whereas `\G` terminates a statement even if you change the delimiter. If this is the explanation, then it has nothing to do with how ancient your server is. It would behave the same with the current version.

Comment: To avoid that ^, try using MySQL Workbench instead of phpadmin .. you don't have to specify delimiters when you create stored procedures, it automatically puts them in for you when you create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `;` to terminate the query, the results are formatted in a table. It has to read all the results before it prints anything, because it has to find the maximum width of each column so they'll all be aligned. If the query returns lots of data it will hang for a while before it starts printing anything.

`\G` makes it print each row vertically, with the columns on separate lines. This allows it to start printing as soon as the database starts returning results.